# Animating the percent of a "percentage bar" during the transition

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a very basic animated percentage bar with `HTML`, `CSS`, and `JS` the only problem is that I am trying to devise a way to also animate the increase and/or decrease of the percentage output to go along with an animated percentage bar. In the example below and in this **[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zL5nhuuv/)** I have successfully created that with the only problem being that it doesn't seem to be the most efficient or effective way of doing it.

In the code snippet directly below I'm creating this animated effect by...

1. Setting `x` equal to setInterval
2. Capturing the width of percent bar on the left and removing the `px` from the end of the string.
3. Capturing the width of percent bar on the right and removing the `px` from the end of the string.
4. Displays the percent value for the left (blue) bar inside the tooltip that can be seen when hovered over.
5. Displays the percent value for the right (red) bar inside the tooltip that can be seen when hovered over.
6. Displays the percent value of the left (blue) bar below the percent bar.
7. Displays the percent value of the right (red) bar below the percent bar.
8. All of this code below will run every `64` Milliseconds.
9. This code will only run for `2000` Milliseconds which is the same amount of time that I have set the transition for the percent bars.

**Note:** The whole point of the code below is to give the illusion that the percent values are increasing as either of the percent bars are increasing. In short, the goal is to make it seem more animated rather than the number all of a sudden seeing the number jump from one number to the next.

There just has to be a better way of achieving the same effect (or better) rather than pulling data from the `DOM` every `64` Milliseconds. There are tons of real-time graph's out on the web that achieve the same effect but I can't figure out how so I came up with my own and don't really think that they do it this way either. Any ideas??? I would only like to use pure Javascript with no libraries such as jQuery.

```js
  var x = setInterval(function() {
    var left = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(p_bar_left).getPropertyValue('width').replace(/px/i, '')) / (parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(p_bar_left).getPropertyValue('width').replace(/px/i, '')) + parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(p_bar_right).getPropertyValue('width').replace(/px/i, ''))) * 100;
    var right = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(p_bar_right).getPropertyValue('width').replace(/px/i, '')) / (parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(p_bar_left).getPropertyValue('width').replace(/px/i, '')) + parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(p_bar_right).getPropertyValue('width').replace(/px/i, ''))) * 100;
    p_bar_left.querySelector('.percent-value').innerText = left.toFixed(2) + '%';
    document.querySelector('#blue').querySelector('.percent-amount').innerText = left.toFixed(2) + '%';
    p_bar_right.querySelector('.percent-value').innerText = right.toFixed(2) + '%';
    document.querySelector('#red').querySelector('.percent-amount').innerText = right.toFixed(2) + '%';
  }, 64);
  setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(x)
  }, 2000);
```

```js
var good = document.querySelector('#good');
var bad = document.querySelector('#bad');
var p_bar_left = document.querySelector('#progressbar-left');
var p_bar_right = document.querySelector('#progressbar-right');
var counter_left = 0;
var counter_right = 0;
var percent_left = 0;
var percent_right = 0;

function changePercent(increment, which) {
  if (which == 'left') {
    counter_left += increment;
  } else if (which == 'right') {
    counter_right += increment;
  } else {
    throw "Don't know which value to increase.";
  }
  percent_left = (counter_left / (counter_left + counter_right)) * 100;
  percent_right = (counter_right / (counter_left + counter_right)) * 100;
  p_bar_left.style.width = percent_left + '%';
  p_bar_right.style.width = percent_right + '%';
  document.querySelector('#total-amount').innerText = counter_right + counter_left;

  var x = setInterval(function() {
    var left = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(p_bar_left).getPropertyValue('width').replace(/px/i, '')) / (parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(p_bar_left).getPropertyValue('width').replace(/px/i, '')) + parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(p_bar_right).getPropertyValue('width').replace(/px/i, ''))) * 100;
    var right = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(p_bar_right).getPropertyValue('width').replace(/px/i, '')) / (parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(p_bar_left).getPropertyValue('width').replace(/px/i, '')) + parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(p_bar_right).getPropertyValue('width').replace(/px/i, ''))) * 100;
    p_bar_left.querySelector('.percent-value').innerText = left.toFixed(2) + '%';
    document.querySelector('#blue').querySelector('.percent-amount').innerText = left.toFixed(2) + '%';
    p_bar_right.querySelector('.percent-value').innerText = right.toFixed(2) + '%';
    document.querySelector('#red').querySelector('.percent-amount').innerText = right.toFixed(2) + '%';
  }, 64);
  setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(x)
  }, 2000);
}

good.addEventListener('click', function() {
  changePercent(1, 'left');
});
bad.addEventListener('click', function() {
  changePercent(1, 'right');
});

var tooltip = document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip');
var tooltipelement = document.querySelectorAll('#progressbar-left, #progressbar-right');

for (var x = tooltipelement.length; x--;) {
  tooltipelement[x].addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    for (var i = tooltip.length; i--;) {
      tooltip[i].style.left = e.pageX + 20 + 'px';
      tooltip[i].style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#progressbar-container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 32px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: #ccc;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#progressbar-left {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: width 2s;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#progressbar-right {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  transition: width 2s;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tooltip {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 6px;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.object {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
}

.percent-value {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
}

#progressbar-left:hover .tooltip {
  display: block;
}

#progressbar-right:hover .tooltip {
  display: block;
}

#total {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#total-amount {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: normal;
}

#blue,
#red {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.percent-amount {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="button" value="Good" id="good">
  <input type="button" value="Bad" id="bad">
  <div id="progressbar-container">
    <div id="progressbar-left">
      <div class="tooltip">
        <span class="tooltiptext">
          <span class="object">Blue</span>
        <span class="percent-value"></span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="progressbar-right">
      <div class="tooltip">
        <span class="tooltiptext">
          <span class="object">Red</span>
        <span class="percent-value"></span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span id="total">Total: <p id="total-amount">0</p></span>
  <span id="blue">Percent Blue: <p class="percent-amount">0%</p></span>
  <span id="red">Percent Red: <p class="percent-amount">0%</p></span>
</body>
```

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zL5nhuuv/)**

Comment: Move this question to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)